# TypeError: object of type 'Bidirectional' has no len()

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I'm running a bidirectional LSTM. But this error is appearing:

**TypeError: object of type 'Bidirectional' has no len()**

What's wrong in this code? Please help.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 from tqdm import tqdm, trange
 import unicodedata

 from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
 from keras.utils import to_categorical
 from keras.models import Model
 from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
 from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Embedding, Dense, TimeDistributed, Dropout, Bidirectional

 # Defining Constants

 # Maximum length of text sentences
 MAXLEN = 180
 # Number of LSTM units
 LSTM_N = 150
 # batch size
 BS=48

 input = Input(shape=(MAXLEN,))

 model = Embedding(input_dim=n_words, output_dim=MAXLEN, input_length=MAXLEN)(input)

 model = Dropout(0.2)(model)

 model = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=LSTM_N, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.1))(model)

 out = TimeDistributed(Dense(n_tags, activation="softmax"))(model)  # softmax output layer

 model = Model(input, out)

 model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
 history = model.fit(X, np.array(y), batch_size=BS, epochs=2, validation_split=0.05, verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

That code instantiates `model` over and over. `model` should be instantiated once and all other layers are added to that instance. Something like this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=n_words, output_dim=MAXLEN, input_length=MAXLEN))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=LSTM_N, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.1)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(n_tags, activation="softmax")))
```